# Adding a new column to acts_as_taggable_on tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

Basically I would like to add the ability to vote on tags, so I would like to have a priority column for each different model's tag.

Any ideas about how to do this?

I suspect I need to make a new migration, but I don't know what to make it for. What would the migration be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I remember, `acts_as_taggable` creates a table called `tags`, so you add a field to that table:

```
rails g migration add_votes_to_tag votes:integer
```

and add your logic to vote on tag.

*P.S. Not sure if I understood correctly your question.*

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but is the other table that it creates not the one that actually links the tag to a different model? I just don't know which one really to add the column to.

Comment: yes, there is a table that links Tag to your models, but you don't put rating for Tag in that table, that table is just to create a relation. If you want to rate your tags you need to add votes to tag table

Comment: or describe more what you want to do, may be I got it all wrong.

Comment: Yea it's hard to explain but I would like to have an individual vote count for each tag of a certain model. So the vote wouldnt be for the tag in general but for the tag of a specific model. Does that make sense?

Comment: I got it, in this case you need to add votes filed to that join table, it's taggings I guess.

Comment: I made the migration but now I need to be able to access the Taggings table, which currently I get:
`uninitialized constant ActsAsTaggableOn::Taggings`

Any idea about how to access items in the taggings table?

Comment: create a model in app/models called Tagging.rb

Comment: Well turns out it was just that extra 's' on Taggings. So just using ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging worked perfectly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend the regular usage of the tag class, seems to be the case, and create a special case for those tags that needs to be counted you can rely on a hook method from the core named `[find_or_create_tags_from_list_with_context][1]`

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_taggable_on :markets, :locations

    def find_or_create_tags_from_list_with_context(tag_list, context)
        if context.to_sym == :markets
            MarketTag.find_or_create_all_with_like_by_name(tag_list)
        else
            super
        end
    end
end
```